# SVN commit vs Git commit

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I know Git has local and remote repo(since distributed), but my doubt is there any difference in SVN commit and Git commit(considering local git commit).

As per my understanding, both `svn` and `git` will maintain a version for the entire project per commit not keeping version only for the committed files as CVS does.Is that true ?

Then, are there any other differences (except the things like the way both systems store the versioning info, committing to local or central repo)?

Answer (score 8):

SVN has no local repo. Therefore svn checkin is used to push your changes into the remote repo.
GIT has a local repo. Commit creates a new 'version' in your local and your local only. Git push is then used to send this changeset into the remote.

I suggest your read this free resource:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2
In particular this chapter should be of interest to you:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain

Answer (score 1):

SVN is a centralized application model.  SVN commit pushes changes from the local client to a centralized repository.
 Git is a distributed application model.  In Git the snapshots are committed to the local repository. Git commits can be pushed to arbitrary remote repositories.
Source: https://www.w3docs.com/learn-git/git-commit.html